# Google Cloud Vision API - Error creating Grpc.Core.Channel

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision, google-client

I am trying to use Google Cloud Vision V1 Api's ImageAnnotatorClient class. I am following the example at https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Vision.V1/api/Google.Cloud.Vision.V1.ImageAnnotatorClient.html under the

> Create(ServiceEndpoint, ImageAnnotatorSettings)

header. I am using C# and trying to build a classic console application. I am using GRPC.Core version 1.15.0, and Google.Cloud.Vision.V1 version 1.2.0 from Nuget. I get a compile error

> 'GoogleCredential' does not contain a definition for
>   'ToChannelCredentials' and no extension method 'ToChannelCredentials'
>   accepting a first argument of type 'GoogleCredential' could be found

The below is my code:

```
GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential
    .FromFile(@"C:\Users\...\12345.json")
    .CreateScoped(ImageAnnotatorClient.DefaultScopes);
            Google.Cloud.Vision.V1.Image image1 = Google.Cloud.Vision.V1.Image.FromFile(@"c:\Users\....\Image14b.png");

            Channel channel = new Channel(
    ImageAnnotatorClient.DefaultEndpoint.Host, ImageAnnotatorClient.DefaultEndpoint.Port, credential.ToChannelCredentials());
            ImageAnnotatorClient client = ImageAnnotatorClient.Create(channel);

            IReadOnlyList<EntityAnnotation> textAnnotations = client.DetectText(image1);
```

I get error at the line below:

```
        Channel channel = new Channel(
ImageAnnotatorClient.DefaultEndpoint.Host, ImageAnnotatorClient.DefaultEndpoint.Port, credential.ToChannelCredentials());
```

Any hints please?

Answer (score 5):

You might be missing one of the using directives, specifically

```
using Grpc.Auth;
```

See [here](https://grpc.io/grpc/csharp/api/Grpc.Auth.GoogleGrpcCredentials.html#Grpc_Auth_GoogleGrpcCredentials_ToChannelCredentials_ITokenAccess_) the definition of `ToChannelCredentials` as an extension method.

Check that you have included all the other `using` directives present in the sample as well.